# How to remove package in bad state, software center freezes, no synaptic

Tags: package-management

When 'Update Manager' starts running, it tells me that I need to do a 'Partial Upgrade', when I start doing the upgrade, it tells me

```
Remove package in bad state 

The package 'linux-headers-3.0.0-19' is in an inconsistent state 
and needs to be reinstalled, but no archive can be found for it. 
Do you want to remove this package now to continue?"
```

When I click 'Yes' the program just closes. I have tried to go into the software center and reinstall the `linux-headers-3.0.0-19` ubuntu software center just freezes.

Right now I cannot run 'Synaptic', or remove any software.

Comment: Have you tried the sudo command of "sudo apt-get --purge remove <package>" and then try re-installing from the CLI?

Comment: I tried it, the command sent back this response:
"E: The package linux-headers-3.0.0-19 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f  <package>` ?

Comment: I got the same message  "E: The package linux-headers-3.0.0-19 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: Try the solution from this guy...

http://askubuntu.com/questions/122699/how-to-remove-package-in-bad-state-software-center-freezes-no-synaptic

Comment: i cant find the line "**linux-headers-3.0.0-19**" There are Tooo Many Lines Is There any easy way to spot the line

Answer (score 57):

Try this, I hope it works:

1. Make a backup of `/var/lib/dpkg/status`:

   ```
   sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bkup
   ```
2. Open `/var/lib/dpkg/status`:

   ```
   sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
3. Search through the file for any reference to that package name (i.e. `linux-headers-3.0.0-19`) and **CAREFULLY** delete that entry. Don't delete anything else. Save the file and quit.
4. Do `sudo apt-get update`.

This should probably solve the problem.

Comment: It works! I got Software Center couldn't be open when installing openfire and your solution works!

Comment: `gedit` did not to open `/var/lib/dpkg/status` because of some special characters. Instead, editing it with `nano` worked fine. Already on two occasions it solved a nagging problem with the `libreoffice-base` package for me.

Comment: it is still works on 16.04

Answer (score 43):

- If you get nowhere with any of the other offerings I've used this in the past

  ```
  dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq
  ```

  From the dpkg manual

  > `remove-reinstreq`:  Remove  a package, even if it's broken
- So run:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  linux-headers-3.0.0-19
  ```