# Forcibly removing zramswap-enabler from my computer

Tags: package-management, zram

zramswap-enabler has put my package manage in an "inconsistent state."

I tried forcibly removing it with this commend:

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq
```

But it seems to freeze and doesn't complete operation.

I tried modifying my dpkg status file as [recommended here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122699/how-to-remove-package-in-bad-state-software-center-freezes-no-synaptic), but that didn't work either. When I tried upgrading my other files, zramswap still showed up, and stopped it from completing.

Are there any other ways I can force remove this file, or will I have to reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I killed dpkg from the background.

```
sudo killall -9 dpkg
```

Removed zram swap references from the dpkg status file.

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bkup
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Removed the zram sources from the package manager.

```
I used the gui.
```

Than ran this.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```