# java installation pending task Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java

I am using `Ubuntu 15.04` `8u45-linux-x64.rpm` and converting it to `.deb` using alien, then I am installing  it using `gdebi package installer`.

now when I run a `apt-get` command I get this error

> E: The package jre1.8.0-45 needs to be reinstalled

but I can't find an archive for it.

anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: And why a RPM and not a DEB or the package manager?

Answer (score 0):

First, [fix the `apt-get` error you're getting](https://askubuntu.com/a/123152/147763). Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jre1.8.0-45
```

---

Once that's fixed, you should instead [install it using WebUpd8's Oracle Java packages](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html), which also automatically give you future updates when you do `apt-get update`.

To do so, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get update
apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```