# var lock issue right after installing JDK and soapUI on my machine

Tags: apt, permissions, java, dpkg, jdk

I have been dealing with an issue all day here. I cannot seem to have apt-get work for anything whatsoever. I have been through several parameters here including trying these following solutions:

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. detect processes to see if I need to establish kill method
4. remounting `r+w` permissions and using `chmod` and/or `chown` methods
5. used `rm -rf` to remove lock files from directories (which I know is not the best solution)
6. tried using autoremove, autoclean, clean,....

I have tried many things and cannot find a proper solution. Is there a way to restore system settings and still keep home files?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you already tried to reboot your system? Sometimes `apt-get` lock disappears when you reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you provide the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade --force-yes` by [edit]ing your question and putting it there or provide a link to http://paste.ubuntu.com?

Comment: Same problem, here's mine:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package jdk1.8.0-77 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
Synaptic also refuses to open, with blocking screen:E: The package jdk1.8.0-77 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/122699/how-to-remove-package-in-bad-state-software-center-freezes-no-synaptic