# Error when using apt-get install to install something on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to install xpad, Wine and get same error.

```
sudo apt-get install xpad
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package jdk1.8.0-101 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How to fix it, thanks.

[UPDATE]
I try to remove jdk1.8.0_101

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  jdk1.8.0-101

dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
(Reading database ... 221715 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jdk1.8.0-101 (1.8.0101-1) ...
find: ‘/usr/java/*’: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-101.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-101.postrm: line 598: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8.0-101 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8.0-101
```

I think I lack the folders because i manually remove it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a package in an inconsistent state which prevents you from installing anything.

You could try answers in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122699/how-to-remove-package-in-bad-state-software-center-freezes-no-synaptic), replacing linux-headers-3.0.0-19 with jdk1.8.0-101, see if it helps.

It's probably a good idea to reinstall the package properly afterwards (chances are something depends on it ...)

Comment: I try this but not work.