# apt-get -f install hangs on Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and when trying to unpack linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic apt hangs indefinitely. I terminated the apt process, removed the stale lock files, and ran:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and the result is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.66.70);
however:
Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 4.4.0.64.68.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-generic
```

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get ugrade
```

with the following result:

```
...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.66.70) but 4.4.0.64.68 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Running
    apt-get -f install
starts the cycle over again and I can't get these issues with apt hanging and linux-generic installing properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic` writes the result in your post?

Comment: @BlueManCZ Gave it a try -- this is what I got: `$ sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-66.87).
linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.`

Comment: Ok, and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem after my computer lost power during an update process. The top answer from this thread helped me:

[How to remove package in bad state, software center freezes, no synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122699/how-to-remove-package-in-bad-state-software-center-freezes-no-synaptic)